# Defining the length of an interval in the Riemann sums

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum, characteristic-functions, set-partition, partitions-for-integration

In the Riemann integration theory, the partition of the studied interval $[a,b]$ is [$P(x,t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Partitions_of_an_interval). But how do we define the length of the subdivided intervals $[x_i , x_{i+1}]$ ? Do we say it is the integral of the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of this interval like this: $$\int\chi_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}(x)dx$$

In this case what integral are we using? The Riemann one? Using Riemann integrals to explain Riemann integrals seems to me a bit surprising...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of an interval $[a,b]$ is $b-a$. No integrals required.